# Outlier Analysis for Ordinal Data

Tags: r, analysis, ordinal

In short, I conducted a satisfaction survey in which surveyees are required to answer on a satisfaction scale from 1 to 7.

Here is an example of what the scatterplot (jittered) between two variables from the data set looks like (I am working on R):

[image]

https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0Bx2Sns2vaI9ycm1tV2pNSWUxQXc

Therefore, the data set I am looking into is formed by ordinal data on which I want to conduct an outlier analysis.

What would you suggest as the best outlier analysis approach for this type of data and how can that be implemented on R?

Thank you so much in advance,

Deuterium

Comment: Looking for unusual combinations of the ordinal variables is one way to search for outliers.  You might be better off going to http://stats.stackexchange.com with this question.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of the other site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your data looks something like this:

```
x = rep(1:7, c(3, 4,17, 21, 48, 118, 93)) 
y = c(
    rep(1:7,c(1,2,0,0,0,0,0)),
    rep(1:7,c(2,0,1,1,0,0,0)),
    rep(1:7,c(10,3,2,1,0,0,1)),
    rep(1:7,c(15,3,1,1,1,0,0)),
    rep(1:7,c(20,10,2,10,3,2,1)),
    rep(1:7,c(40,20,20,30,3,4,1)),
    rep(1:7,c(50,25,10,5,3,0,0))
)
```

the plot:

```
library(car)
sp(x,y, jitter = list(x=0.8, y=0.8), smoother=F, reg.line = F)
```

[image]

If you just want to know whether a given value is an outlier in your data 
(i.e. a univariate outlier analysis), you can use:

```
library(outliers)
grubbs.test(x)
```

or simply use `boxplot` which values are plotted as outliers:

```
boxplot(x, plot=F)$out
```

If you need multivariate outliers, you can use the `mvoutlier` package 
(see functions `?chisq.plot` and `?pcout`):

```
library(mvoutlier)
pcout(x=data.frame(x,y))
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I am currently pre-occupied with some other work before I move to outlier analysis, but I'll test your advice out as soon as I get the time to.